# Routing signal though Composition Software Component

Tags: autosar

How can I route a "signal" though a Software Composition without having to copy it (with some code)?
Use-case: The SW-Composition has some RPorts where the data has to be modified and then provided on some PPorts. But for some RPorts/PPorts combination the data does not need to be touched and therefore "simply routed" from RPort to PPort.
The idea would be to simply connect the RPortPrototype with the PPortPrototype with a DelegationSwConnector. But as per specification this is not possible.
Any idea how to do this without the need of "copy-code"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that your P- and R- ports are on the composition itself (that is, they are outer ports), you can use the pass-through connector (`PassThroughSwConnector` model element) for your use case. It's a child element of compositions, so you add a `PassThroughSwConnector` to your `CompositionSwComponentType`, and use it to connect your two ports directly.

Note that this will be impossible if there's another path between the two ports via assembly connectors. That would create a loop consisting of pass-through and assembly connectors, which is explicitly forbidden in the specification.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Now that I knew what to search for in the specification it seems that the PassThroughSwConnector was introduced in AR Version 4.1 (and that's why I did not know it yet).
Again, thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Software Compositions are only a structural grouping. Before generating the Rte, you have to run a tool that creates an "EcuExtract" (see System Template) which flattens the model. So, the input for the Rte is one big root composition that contains atomic components only and no further compositions. Therefore, there will be no "copy node" and data is alway passed through.

However, (with some limitations) it is possible that in the Ecu Extract the port of the root composition has a different type then the port of the component which will lead to data conversion (e.g. rescaling the data or picking an element out of a structure).

Comment: I understand that a Software-Composition has no code and "disappears" when flattening.
But my question was another one: I have a Receiver Port and a Sender Port. I want to directly connect the SenderPort with the ReceiverPort so that I do not need to generate any code for this.

Comment: What you maybe mean is the "pass through connector".

Comment: Yes please check the PassThroughSwConnector in the software component template

Comment: Yes there is a PassThroughSwConnector in the software component template.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.
But I think it's part of a software COMPOSITION (not component).
But anyway, thanks!